# Calculate the length of a side of triangle in C

Tags: c, function, geometry

I am trying to write a program that calculates the length of one side of a triangle with the help of the Pythagoras equation (c²=a²+b²). The user must have the option to choose what side he want to calculate, this is what I have tried:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
// Pitagora:
//          c=sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2));
//          a=sqrt(pow(c,2)-pow(b,2));
//          b=sqrt(pow(c,2)-pow(a,2));
int cateta(int x, int y){
    int cat;
    printf("Dati marimea lui:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Dati marimea lui:");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    cat=sqrt(pow(x,2)-pow(y,2));
    return cat;
}
int main(){

    int a,b,c;
    char l;
    printf("Ce latura doriti sa aflati?");
    printf("\n c : ipotenuza\n a : cateta alaturata\n b : cateta opusa\n");
    printf("Introduceti litera laturei respective : ");
    scanf("%s", &l);
    if (l == a){
        a=cateta(c,b);
        printf("Marimea catetei alaturate este: %d", a);
    }
    else if (l == b){
        b=cateta(c,a);
        printf("Marimea catetei opuse este: %d", b);
    }
    else {
    c=sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2));
    printf("Marimea ipotenuzei este: %d", c);
    printf("\n");
    }
    getch ();
    return 0;

}
```

But, for some reason when I give a value of `a` to the variable `&l` the program displays the content of this piece of code: `printf("Marimea ipotenuzei este: %d", c);` instead of scaning the value of x and y, and terminates. Here is a picture with the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzk3osw1t8729et/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: `scanf("%s", &l);` change to `scanf(" %c", &l);`

Comment: Aslo, just a suggestion, please provide some comments in English. Will be easy to understand.

Comment: Your question does not match the title.

Comment: also, `if (l == a)`,  `(l == b)` is wrong. maybe what you want is `if (l == 'a')`

Comment: I see uninitialized variables: `if (l == a)` at this point, `a` has not been assigned any value. Did you walk through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Also, questions should contain all the relevant information. If the image is relevant, post it here. If it is not relevant, don't post it here. But don't post links to DropBox.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I don't have enough point's to post a image here.
@DanielDaranas I made a mistake there, as @SouravGhosh says I should use `'a'` instead of `a` there.

Comment: Please don't use an image to show plain text output. In general, posters with a higher reputation are happy to insert an image, but only if it is relevant. Just copy the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, u need to change the scanf statement to scanf( "%c",&l);
Now the variable l contains the character entered by user.
Next, during comparison change the if condition to if(l=='a') , if( l=='b') as a and b are character literals.

With this changes, the program should work! 
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

you are using `%s` in `scanf()` for a character type variable, instead use this

```
scanf(" %c", &l);
```